# J-1 Visa Interview - Intent to return to home country

Tags: usa, south-african-citizens, j1-visas, working-holiday

I am worried about my son not having sufficient ties to supply for his interview next week to get a U.S. visa to work as a counselor at a summer camp for 3 months through a reputable company (Camp Leaders).

He has the following:

- Valid passport,
- Employment contract from the Camp he will be working for in the US
- confirmed DS-160,
- US Department of State DS-2019 - CERTIFICATE OF ELIGIBILITY FOR EXCHANGE VISITOR (J-1) STATUS,
- SEVIS I-901 Fee Receipt

He is 20 years old, does not have a permanent job, does not own anything, lives with my parents rent free, and has not studied or made any future study plans yet.

Will this all matter, since he is going to work in the USA for only 3 months?

Comment: FYI, He is a living citizen of South Africa

Comment: It’s up in the air. No harm in trying however I think his chance are slim since he doesn’t have any concrete study plans back home and is not even a recent grad. Not to sound judgmental but he sounds like a drifter and such profiles typically don’t get approved.

Comment: To the close voters: this concerns a short-term summer job.  In my opinion it belongs here, not on [Expatriates.SE].